Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)
I cannot connect to the database and do migration even though my connection string works fine when I connect SQL Server Management Studio through Docker file, I wonder what am I doing wrong.
my connection string with dbcontext
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "SqlServer": "Server=localhost;Database=socialdb;User Id=sa;Password=Str0ngs@Passw0rd21;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}

  public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastractureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
  {
      var connectionstring = configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer");
 

      services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>((sp, options) =>
      {
          options.UseSqlServer(connectionstring);
      }
      );
      return services;
  } 

This is the actual code that throw an exceptios
public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync(this WebApplication app)
    {
        using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
        context.Database.MigrateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

and final docker file

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    # environment:
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: vondella
    #   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: V0ndella21
    volumes:
      - ./db_data/:/data/db/

  socialdb:
    container_name: socialdb
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngs@Passw0rd21
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    # volumes:
    #   - mssql_data:/var/opt/mssql/data

  messagebroker:
    container_name: messagebroker
    hostname: ecomerce-mq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      

  postqueryapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8080
    ports:
      - "8080"

an exception thrown

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)


Well, is SQL Server running on localhost as in your own computer? For docker, localhost means docker's localhost, which isn't the same as computer's dito

SQL server is running on docker, but with the same connection string works fine when i try to connect  using sql server management studio

So, think about it, for docker, your computer might as well to be on mars for all it knows. You can install ssms in docker and see that it will fail against localhost as well

.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); <-- Don't do this; your InitializeDatabaseAsync method supports async so just add the async modifier and change the last line to await context.Database.MigrateAsync().

Assuming postqueryapi is trying to connect to the SQL database then in the connection string:
 "SqlServer": "Server=localhost;Database=socialdb;User Id=sa;Password=Str0ngs@Passw0rd21;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=True"

localhost will mean the container itself which clearly does not have the instance of the database running.
Instead of the localhost  you can try using 1) host.docker.internal (i.e. Server=host.docker.internal, it should work on Windows) 2) the database container name (Server=socialdb, since all containers are in the same default network, or you can move them in the same non-default one)

but with the same connection string works fine when i try to connect using sql server management studio

Because you map the port for the local machine, so when you are using SSMS it will use the 1433 of localhost mapped to 1433 port of the docker container.
See also:

Docker: Networking overview
Wiki: Localhost

